# How can I get the Month/Weekday names in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, date, time

How can I get the Month/Weekday names in GWT?

I try it like this, but there must exist a better solution for this problem (i hope :) ):

```
public String getLocalizedName() {
    switch( this ) {
        case Januar:
            return getMonth( 1 );
        case February:
            return getMonth( 2 );
        case March:
            return getMonth( 3 );
        case April:
            return getMonth( 4 );
        case May:
            return getMonth( 5 );
        case June:
            return getMonth( 6 );
        case July:
            return getMonth( 7 );
        case August:
            return getMonth( 8 );
        case September:
            return getMonth( 9 );
        case October:
            return getMonth( 10 );
        case November:
            return getMonth( 11 );
        case December:
            return getMonth( 12 );
    }
    return "";
}

private String getMonth( int month ) {

    return DateTimeFormat.getFormat( DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.MONTH_ABBR ).format( new Date( 2011, month, 1 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you want to format or just a list of the months/days. The localized string can be obtained 
from `DateTimeFormatInfo`:

```
//returns a String array with localized names of the months
String[] months = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getDateTimeFormatInfo().monthsFull();

//returns a String array with localized names of days of the week
String[] weekdays = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getDateTimeFormatInfo().weekdaysFull();
```